# Center Adsense banner inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, banner

I have in my website a space for adsense banner.

I have customized space with max-height and max-width for force system to display only banner that are max 940px width and 180px height. Now i need to center banner.

I tried with `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.
I also tried with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.
But the banner has still displayed at left at margin of page.

### HTML

```
<div id="footer_ad">
   <div style="max-height:180; max-width:940; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
       <?php echo $footer_ad; ?>
   </div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I think problem is with parent div's styling

Comment: Are you saying you think the "father" div is the problem, and you haven't included it's definition here?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the issue in a simple snippet that you can include here? The PHP include makes it so we don't know what is actually there in the rendered HTML.

Comment: Yes, i tried to add to first div. same thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was just a small typo and should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use flex center Div... So add some thing like this to your css

```
.footer_ad {
  height: yourheight;
  max-width: yourmaxwidth;
  margin: 40px auto 40px auto;
  display: flex;
}

.center-ad {
  margin: auto;
}

//Html should be like this 
<div class="footer_ad">
   <div class="center_ad">
       <?php echo $footer_ad; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix problem...
is a forgetfulness :-(
i not write "px"
Now with this code work:

```
<div id="footer_ad">
   <div style="max-height:180px; max-width:940px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
       <?php echo $footer_ad; ?>
   </div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if your error was just a small typo then please just delete the question